# JPanel#setVisible not working.

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

i have problems in the visibility of JPanel using Netbeans;  i made a simple example to show you what happens.
Netbeans creates the code when i design the combo and the panel -> until "private void TheFrame(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)".

In the windowActivated of the frame i put the panelOne(JPanel).setVisible(false) and 
this works !
After chosing an item(item2/item4) from the combo i would like the panelOne to be shown but this does not work.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Alessandro
 */
public class UIFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form UIFrame
     */
    public UIFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panelOne = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        comboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                TheFrame(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelOneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelOne);
        panelOne.setLayout(panelOneLayout);
        panelOneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelOneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 349, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panelOneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelOneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        comboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        comboBox.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                ItemListener(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(panelOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(122, 122, 122)
                        .addComponent(comboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(comboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(panelOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void TheFrame(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                          
        panelOne.setVisible(false);
    }                         

    private void ItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                              
        String test = (String)(evt.getItem());   
        switch (test)
        {
            case "Item1":
                panelOne.setVisible(false);
            case "Item2":
                panelOne.setVisible(true);
            case "Item3":
                panelOne.setVisible(false);
            case "Item4":
                panelOne.setVisible(true);
        }               
    }                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UIFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UIFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox comboBox;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelOne;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: please paste the complete code. Did you add the combobox to the panel?

Comment: No,  the comboBox is outside the Panel

Answer (score 3):

Your `switch-case` is incorrect. You are having wrong strings for cases and also you are missing the break statements.

The items that you have added are

```
"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" and "Item 4"
```

whereas in the switch case, you are comparing

```
"item1", "item2", "item3" and "item4"
```

Second, I believe part of the problem is the way you are getting the selected string. Try to use this method instead:

```
private void ItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    String test = (String) (evt.getItem()); //do not use this
    System.out.println(test);

    JComboBox box = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
    String selectedString = (String) box.getSelectedItem();

    switch (selectedString) { //replaced test with selectedString
    case "Item 1":
        panelOne.setVisible(false); break;
    case "Item 2":
        panelOne.setVisible(true); break;
    case "Item 3":
        panelOne.setVisible(false); break;
    case "Item 4":
        panelOne.setVisible(true); break;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. The cause of the problem could be the fact that when you change an item in a combobox, the item selection change event is fired twice. First, for the deselected item and then for the selected item.

As you can see I have added a `println()` for `test` and the new `selectedString` variable. Now, if your current selection is "Item 1" and you select "Item 3", then two `ItemEvent` will be fired, the value for `test` will be different in both cases as it refers to different items, whereas the selected item will be the same, as you would probably want.

> PS: This is why you need the break statement.
>   When you write:

```
switch(var){
case 1: doOne();
case 2: doTwo();
case 3: doThree();
}
```

what happens when `case 1` succeeds is that all the cases below it are not checked and will be executed sequentially. So, all of `doOne()`, `doTwo()` and `doThree()` will be executed.

```
switch(var){
case 1: doOne(); break;
case 2: doTwo(); break;
case 3: doThree(); break;
}
```

What this does is that whenever a case succeeds and its corresponding code is executed, `break` will terminate the `switch-case` thereby executing only the code that you want to execute.

To avoid this, you need to use break statements:

Also, here is the code that I have

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class UIFrame extends JFrame {
    final private JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox comboBox;

    public UIFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        comboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        comboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
                "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        comboBox.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                ItemListener(evt);
            }
        });
        panelOne.add(new JTextField("Hello"));
        add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panelOne, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }


    private void ItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        panelOne.setVisible(false);
        String test = (String) (evt.getItem());
        System.out.println(test);

        JComboBox box = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
        String selectedString = (String) box.getSelectedItem();

        switch (selectedString) {
        case "Item 1":
            panelOne.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "Item 2":
            panelOne.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case "Item 3":
            panelOne.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "Item 4":
            panelOne.setVisible(true);
            break;
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final UIFrame frame = new UIFrame();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but that's not the problem; i changed the Strings and it is the same. The Panel does not appear

Comment: By the way in the code that you have right now, the strings are still wrong. You are missing the space. Use "Item 1" instead of "Item1"

Comment: I did not see your last change, let me try

Comment: impossible to cancel some parts in netbeans ... but i will change switch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25625/discussion-between-ankit-and-alpan67)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `if ...else` rather than `switch Statement` then it is more easy to code and also understand if you are new in java language.

just try this code at **jComboBox** event

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
       PanelChange();
    } 


 private void PanelChange() {
         String test = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (test.equals("Item 1") || test.equals("Item 3")) {
            jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        }else{
            jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

The reason for creating **PanelChange()**  is that at the first time "Item 1" is a selected item and as per your statements when **"Item 1"** is selected then **jPanel** is not visible for that you must copy this method in constructor like :

```
public UIFrame() {
        initComponents();
        PanelChange();
    }
```